# $D_\mathfrak p$ is a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let

- $K$ be a number field (i.e. $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a finite extensions).
- $G_K:=\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ be its absolute Galois group.
- $\mathfrak p \in K$ be a prime ideal over $p$
- $\mathfrak P \in \overline{K}$ a prime ideal over $\mathfrak p$.
- $D_\mathfrak P$ the decomposition group of $\mathfrak P$.

I'm trying to understand decomposition groups in infinite extensions. I'm not sure I've got even the definitions right, so feel free to nitpick.

I guess the definition of decomposition group of $\mathfrak P$ should be (generalizing for example the one in Neukirch I.9 for finite extensions) $D_\mathfrak P:= \{\rho \in G_K | \rho \mathfrak P= \mathfrak P \}$. Is this correct?

What I want to prove is

> $D_\mathfrak P$ is a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ in the Krull topology.

Here is my attempt (closely based on Neukirch II.9 for local valuations):

> $D_\mathfrak P \subseteq G_K$ by definition. Let $\rho \in G_K$ belong
>   to the closure of $D_\mathfrak P$.
>
> This means that in every neighbourhood $\rho
>  \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/M)$ there is some element $\rho_M$ of
>   $D_\mathfrak P$, as $M/K$ varies over all finite subextensions of
>   $\overline{K}/K$.
>
> Since $\rho_M \in \rho \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/M)$, we have
>    $\rho_M|_M=\rho_M$, and $\mathfrak P \circ \rho_M= \mathfrak P$
>   implies that $\mathfrak P \circ \rho_M= \mathfrak P \circ
>  \rho_M|_M=\mathfrak P$.
>
> As $\overline{K}$ is the union of all $M$, we get that $\mathfrak P
>  \circ \rho = \mathfrak P$, so that $\rho \in D_\mathfrak P$. Therefore
>    $D_\mathfrak P$ is closed in $G_K$.

Is this correct? I'm very interested in understanding this correctly, so feel free to point out even minor mistakes.

Comment: Because $\rho\vert_M=\rho_M\vert_M$ is defined only on $M$, I might rephrase some late steps to read
$$\rho(\mathfrak P \cap M)=\rho_M(\mathfrak P \cap M)=\mathfrak P \cap M.$$
And then use the fact that $\mathfrak P$ is the union of $\mathfrak P\cap M$ with $M$ varying to conclude that $\rho\in D_{\mathfrak{P}}$. I'm not too familiar with this, so caveats apply.

Comment: In fact, Neukirch gives a brief proof right after Definition 9.3.